# Keras Model output shape is "(None,)"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My model includes a previously loaded model, and gives an output shape of "(None,)":

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Input, Subtract, Multiply, Lambda

x = Input((158,))
y = model(x)
c = Subtract()([x,y])
c = Multiply()([c,c])
d = Lambda(lambda arg: tf.keras.backend.mean(arg,axis=1), output_shape = (None,1))
e = d(c)

new_model = Model(inputs = x, outputs = e)
new_model.summary()

Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 158)]        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
model_1 (Model)                 (None, 158)          57310       input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
subtract (Subtract)             (None, 158)          0           input_1[0][0]                    
                                                                 model_1[1][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
multiply (Multiply)             (None, 158)          0           subtract[0][0]                   
                                                                 subtract[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda (Lambda)                 (None,)              0           multiply[0][0]                   
==================================================================================================
Total params: 57,310
Trainable params: 57,310
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

This model outputs correct values, but it might be creating issues down the line with the next step of my work, so I would like to know what this output shape means, and if I have to correct it (as I saw no exemples of this case online).

*Edit*

To specify, I'm not investigating about the `None` value, but the fact that it doesn't say `(None,1)`, is it the same thing ?

As an exemple, this summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 4
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 3
=================================================================
Total params: 7
Trainable params: 7
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

source: https://machinelearningmastery.com/visualize-deep-learning-neural-network-model-keras/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to reshape the last layer into a `(None,1)`, and it did solve an issue in my code, I did it by adding a `Reshape` layer to my model:

```
x = Input(158,)
y = model(x)
c = Subtract()([x,y])
c = Multiply()([c,c])
d = Lambda(lambda arg: tf.keras.backend.mean(arg,axis=1), output_shape = (None,1))
e = d(c)
f = Reshape([1])(e)

new_model = Model(inputs = x, outputs = f)
```

Which gives:

```
new_model.summary()

Model: "model_4"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)            [(None, 158)]        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
model_1 (Model)                 (None, 158)          57310       input_5[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
subtract_4 (Subtract)           (None, 158)          0           input_5[0][0]                    
                                                                 model_1[5][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
multiply_4 (Multiply)           (None, 158)          0           subtract_4[0][0]                 
                                                                 subtract_4[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_4 (Lambda)               (None,)              0           multiply_4[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
reshape_3 (Reshape)             (None, 1)            0           lambda_4[0][0]                   
==================================================================================================
Total params: 57,310
Trainable params: 57,310
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 3):

None here represents your `batch size`. Batch size value is dynamic, you define it later during `.fit()` so before the definition it doesn't know the size and it stays `None` meaning any positive integer value.

You can read [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/) to understand parameters and values a bit better.

Comment: I had read that but I was expecting an output shape of `(None,1)`, similarly to this tutorial : https://machinelearningmastery.com/visualize-deep-learning-neural-network-model-keras/